# Adjust the Scatter Gather List buffer Address and lengths

Tags: c++, c

I have a original allocated SGL array of structures that contain buffer address and lengths. We need to prepare a temporary  SGL array based off original SGL structure array meeting few requirements and later use the temporary SGL array for crypto operations.

Requirement: Ignore the first 8 bytes and last 10 bytes

```
    // Buffer data structure
    typedef struct
    {
      void *data_addr;
      int  data_len; 
    }T_BUF_DATA;

    Final Array:
    T_BUF_DATA final_array[100];

    Case1:
        Original array: T_BUF_DATA[0] = buf_addr = 0xabc, buf_len = 1
                        T_BUF_DATA[1] = buf_addr = 0xdef, buf_len = 10
                        T_BUF_DATA[2] = buf_addr = 0x123, buf_len = 23

        final_array[0] = buf_addr =( 0xdef + 7 ), buf_len =  ( 10 - 7 ) // since we need to ignore the first 8 bytes from original list, adjust the buf_Addr by offset of 7  bytes
        final_array[1] = buf_addr = 0x123, buf_len = ( 23 - 10 ) .. since we need to ignore the last 10 bytes


Case2:
        Original array: T_BUF_DATA[0] = buf_addr = 0xabc, buf_len = 100

        final_array[0] = buf_addr = ( 0xabc + 8 ), buf_len = 100 - ( 8 + 10 );
```

We need to implement a generic solution that can handle all the varying buffer length original array structures while preparing the final array.  Can someone please assist me here ? I am able to handle the case 2, but stuck on attempting case 1 and any few other unknown corner cases.

```
void adjust_my_original_buffer ( T_BUF_DATA *data, int num_bufs )
    {

       T_BUF_DATA final_array[100];
       int idx = 0;

       for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_bufs; i++ )
    {

       // prepare the final array

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work. The idea is to skip whole SG entries at the start (keeping track of remaining initial bytes to be skipped in `initial_skip`) and skip whole SG entries at the end (keeping track of remaining final bytes to be skipped in `final_skip`) in order to simplify the problem.

After the simplification, there may be 0, 1 or more SG entries remaining, indicated by the adjusted `num_bufs`, and the adjusted `orig` points to the first remaining entry.  If there is at least one remaining SG entry, the first entry's `data_len` will be greater than `initial_skip` and the last entry's `data_len` will be greater than `final_skip`.  If there is exactly one remaining SG entry, an additional test is required to check that its `data_len` is greater than `initial_skip + final_skip`, reducing the number of remaining SG entries to zero if that is not the case.

A loop copies the remaining SG entries from `orig` to `final` and the `if` statements within the loop adjust the first and last SG entries (which might be a single SG entry).

Finally, the function returns the length of the final SG list, which could be 0 if everything was skipped.

```
int adjust_my_original_buffer ( const T_BUF_DATA * restrict orig, T_BUF_DATA * restrict final, int num_bufs )
{
    int initial_skip;
    int final_skip;

    // Skip initial bytes.
    initial_skip = 8;
    while ( num_bufs && orig[0].data_len <= initial_skip )
    {
        initial_skip -= orig[0].data_len;
        orig++;
        num_bufs--;
    }
    // Skip final bytes.
    final_skip = 10;
    while ( num_bufs && orig[num_bufs - 1].data_len <= final_skip )
    {
        final_skip -= orig[num_bufs - 1].data_len;
        num_bufs--;
    }
    // If single SG entry remaining, check its length.
    if ( num_bufs == 1 && data[0].data_len <= initial_skip + final_skip )
    {
        // Singleton SG entry is too short.
        num_bufs = 0;
    }
    // Copy SG entries to final list, adjusting first and last entry.
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_bufs; i++ )
    {
        final[i] = orig[i]; // Copy SG entry.
        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            // Adjust first SG entry.
            final[i].data_addr = (char *)final[i].data_addr + initial_skip;
            final[i].data_len -= initial_skip;
        }
        if ( i == num_bufs - 1 )
        {
            // Adjust last SG entry.
            final[i].data_len -= final_skip;
        }
    }
    return num_bufs;
}
```

Comment: thanks. In the first while loop, orig[0].date_len is checked in every iteration. I THINK THIS IS A TYPO. the right one should be orig[num_buff] ?

Comment: @user13000627 No, because the `orig++;` skips an entry so that `orig[1]` becomes `orig[0]` for the next iteration.

Comment: Ah.. I see ..Thanks again

Comment: I realized that an extra check was needed in the case where a single SG entry remains after the simplification to make sure its length is greater than the total remaining skip amount from the beginning and end. I have edited the answer and the code accordingly.

Comment: I've also corrected the position of the `restrict` qualifier on the function parameters. The `restrict` qualifier should apply to the pointers themselves, not to the data they point to.